# How do I work with get/set methods when using char type variables

Tags: java, variables, methods, char, set

I'm developing a sort of a matrix calculator that operates with 2 matrices.

First you have to set the number of rows and columns, then you name and fill each matrix.

This might be a silly thing to ask here but I'm having a hard time importing the setter for the name method, which works with a char type variable.

Here's the name method:

```
public void setName(char name) {
    System.out.printf("\n%s\n%s", "NEW MATRIX", "Name your matrix: ");
    name = input.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println();
    this.name = name;
}

public char getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Now here's the part I can't get my head round:

```
build.setName();
```

This line is in my main class. Everything there is OK, only this one line is underlined in red.
I tried putting a "0" and a "null" in the parenthesis but it didn't work.

Please, can anybody help me sort this out?

Comment: Try `'0'` with single quotes (not double quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chars use single quotes 
ie

```
build.setName('0');
```